# Accessing HBase through Spark with Security enabled

Tags: security, hadoop, apache-spark, hbase, kerberos

I'm trying to run a spark job that accesses HBase with security enabled. When i run the following command:

> /usr/local/spark-2/bin/spark-submit --keytab
>   /etc/hadoop/conf/spark.keytab --principal
>   spark/hadoop-master@platalyticsrealm --class
>   com.platalytics.example.spark.App --master yarn  --driver-class-path
>   /root/hbase-1.2.2/conf /home/vm6/project-1-jar-with-dependencies.jar

I get the following error:

```
2016-08-07 20:43:57,617 WARN  [hconnection-0x24b5fa45-metaLookup-shared--pool2-t1] ipc.RpcClientImpl: Exception encountered while connecting to the server : javax.security.sasl.SaslException: GSS initiate failed [Caused by GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Failed to find any Kerberos tgt)]
2016-08-07 20:43:57,619 ERROR [hconnection-0x24b5fa45-metaLookup-shared--pool2-t1] ipc.RpcClientImpl: SASL authentication failed. The most likely cause is missing or invalid credentials. Consider 'kinit'.
javax.security.sasl.SaslException: GSS initiate failed [Caused by GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Failed to find any Kerberos tgt)]
    at com.sun.security.sasl.gsskerb.GssKrb5Client.evaluateChallenge(GssKrb5Client.java:212)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.security.HBaseSaslRpcClient.saslConnect(HBaseSaslRpcClient.java:179)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientImpl$Connection.setupSaslConnection(RpcClientImpl.java:617)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientImpl$Connection.access$700(RpcClientImpl.java:162)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientImpl$Connection$2.run(RpcClientImpl.java:743)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientImpl$Connection$2.run(RpcClientImpl.java:740)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1657)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientImpl$Connection.setupIOstreams(RpcClientImpl.java:740)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientImpl$Connection.writeRequest(RpcClientImpl.java:906)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientImpl$Connection.tracedWriteRequest(RpcClientImpl.java:873)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientImpl.call(RpcClientImpl.java:1241)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.AbstractRpcClient.callBlockingMethod(AbstractRpcClient.java:227)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.AbstractRpcClient$BlockingRpcChannelImplementation.callBlockingMethod(AbstractRpcClient.java:336)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.protobuf.generated.ClientProtos$ClientService$BlockingStub.scan(ClientProtos.java:34094)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ClientSmallScanner$SmallScannerCallable.call(ClientSmallScanner.java:201)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ClientSmallScanner$SmallScannerCallable.call(ClientSmallScanner.java:180)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCaller.callWithoutRetries(RpcRetryingCaller.java:210)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ScannerCallableWithReplicas$RetryingRPC.call(ScannerCallableWithReplicas.java:360)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ScannerCallableWithReplicas$RetryingRPC.call(ScannerCallableWithReplicas.java:334)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCaller.callWithRetries(RpcRetryingCaller.java:136)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ResultBoundedCompletionService$QueueingFuture.run(ResultBoundedCompletionService.java:65)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Failed to find any Kerberos tgt)
    at sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5InitCredential.getInstance(Krb5InitCredential.java:147)
    at sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5MechFactory.getCredentialElement(Krb5MechFactory.java:121)
    at sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5MechFactory.getMechanismContext(Krb5MechFactory.java:187)
    at sun.security.jgss.GSSManagerImpl.getMechanismContext(GSSManagerImpl.java:223)
    at sun.security.jgss.GSSContextImpl.initSecContext(GSSContextImpl.java:212)
    at sun.security.jgss.GSSContextImpl.initSecContext(GSSContextImpl.java:179)
    at com.sun.security.sasl.gsskerb.GssKrb5Client.evaluateChallenge(GssKrb5Client.java:193)
    ... 25 more
```

I have Spark running on Yarn with security enabled. I have kinit'd from console and have provided necessarry principals and keytabs. Can you please help me find out the issue?

Comment: I have seen similar questions multiple times on S.O. => do your homework!

Comment: Yes i have seen the similar questions but no resolution found yet!